# ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password; -- fails with syntax error

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Trying to enable regular password-based auth according to the below page:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/

The page suggests the following code:

```
ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password;
SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('foo');
```

but on my machine it fails with a syntax error:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password' at line 1
MariaDB [(none)]> SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('foo');
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.38-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ALTER USER](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/alter-user/) "MariaDB starting with 10.2.0"

So 10.1 is too early. Also `mysqld --version` or `SELECT VERSION()` to show the version. `mysql --version` only shows the client version.

Comment: Looks correct according to the documentation, from what I can tell.

Comment: 10.1.38 is a major version too early. Will work in 10.2.0+

Answer (score 12):

If you're running MariaDB < 10.2, the `ALTER USER` command will not work, as stated above.

To change the authentication method, use:

```sql
UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password' WHERE user = 'root';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '************';
```

Worked with me.
I'm using mariaDB: 10.4.20-MariaDB

Comment: The original poster had MariaDB 10.1, which, as noted elsewhere, does not support `ALTER USER`.